# WinForms BindingComplete is triggered by another property

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a TextBox whose Text property is bound to a ViewModel property called Name and a Button whose Enable property is bound to a ViewModel property called IsBusy.

And the TexBox Binding implements BindingComplete that changes the TextBox's background color if an exception is thrown by the property.

The problem is that BindingComplete is also raised when IsBusy property changes which the IsBusy property binding is not subscribing, and the BindingComplete event argument has the BindingField and BindingMember of "Name" and the associated control of this binding is TextBox.

Why IsBusy property is raising BindingComplete that is bound to the Name property?

Because of this, after I force TextBox binding to call WriteValue() to validate the property which sets the background color as expected when there is an error, and assign a true value to IsBusy property to indicate it is busy, it sets the background color back to White, because IsBusy raises TextBox's BindingComplete without an exception.

FYI, I'm intentionally raising PropertyChanged events and throwing exceptions because I want the incorrect values to be entered for users to review.

This is just a demonstration of the problem I'm having. I have more complex business requirements when errors occur. So, it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide an explanation of why this is happening and how to prevent it or fix it.

[image]

```
public partial class BindingTestForm : Form
{
    private TestViewModel viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    public BindingTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        var textBoxTextBinding = new Binding(nameof(TextBox.Text), viewModel, nameof(TestViewModel.Name), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBoxTextBinding.BindingComplete += TextBoxTextBinding_BindingComplete;
        NameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(textBoxTextBinding);

        var enableBinding = new Binding(nameof(Control.Enabled), viewModel, nameof(TestViewModel.IsBusy));
        enableBinding.Format += EnableBinding_Format;
        SaveButton.DataBindings.Add(enableBinding);

        Load += BindingTestForm_Load;
    }

    private void EnableBinding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Value = !(bool)e.Value;
    }

    private void TextBoxTextBinding_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
            NameTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            NameTextBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    private async void BindingTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });
        viewModel.IsBusy = false;
    }

    public class TestViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TestViewModel.Name)));
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
                    throw new Exception("Please enter package name.");
                if (_name.Length > 5)
                    throw new Exception("Max length 5.");
            }
        }
        public bool _isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy 
        { 
            get => _isBusy; 
            set 
            { 
                _isBusy = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TestViewModel.IsBusy)));
            } 
        } 
    }

    private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameTextBox.DataBindings[nameof(TextBox.Text)].WriteValue();

        viewModel.IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });
        viewModel.IsBusy = false;
    }
}


partial class BindingTestForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.NameTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SaveButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // NameTextBox
        // 
        this.NameTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.NameTextBox.Name = "NameTextBox";
        this.NameTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.NameTextBox.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // SaveButton
        // 
        this.SaveButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 75);
        this.SaveButton.Name = "SaveButton";
        this.SaveButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.SaveButton.TabIndex = 1;
        this.SaveButton.Text = "Save";
        this.SaveButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.SaveButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SaveButton_Click);
        // 
        // BindingTestForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SaveButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NameTextBox);
        this.Name = "BindingTestForm";
        this.Text = "FlowLayoutTestForm";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox NameTextBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button SaveButton;
}
```

Comment: Use the Validating event of the textbox instead. Have you considered working with the ErrorProvider component and IErrorDataInfo interface instead?

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes There are many alternate ways to do this, but I'd like to use MVVM as much as possible. And I'm really curious why this is happening.

Comment: IMHO you are overcomplicating things a bit. There could be some `IsValid` property in the ViewModel that you could bind to `BackColor` (with `bool` -> `Color` formatting if you wish). Btw, [here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo) is a small MVVM demo of mine (both for WinForms and WPF), maybe that also can give you some ideas.

Comment: `ErrorProvider` and `IErrorDataInfo` and also @GyörgyKőszeg's solution allow you to put the logic into the View Model instead of working with events in the form. This is what MVVM is all about.

Comment: @György Kőszeg Well, this is just to show the problem, and in my actual project, I need to change the text box border color which cannot be bound and I need to set tooltip text.

Comment: The ErrorProvider component shows an icon as well as a tooltip. And it does so automatically, if your view model implements `IErrorDataInfo`.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes The business requirement I have is to set the border color to red, not showing an info icon.

Comment: _"I need to change the text box border color which cannot be bound"_ - why don't you just create a derived text box with `BorderColor` and/or `ErrorText` property so you can bind it?

Comment: You can bind class properties to any property of the textbox. The solution of @GyörgyKőszeg can do this. Let the view model expose Color proprerties you can bind to the border color and also implement INotifyPropertyChanged to inform the form when these properties change (in the setter of the property bound to the textbox text).

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes Thank you for the suggestions, it is one of the alternate ways to do this. But what I'm truly seeking here is the answer to why this is happening not the workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I must confess that I don't know why this happens.

As an alternative solution, I suggest you to create a text box control being able to display a red border as well as a tooltip.

```cs
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

    private readonly ToolTip _toolTip = new ToolTip();
    private bool _hasError;

    private string _toolTipText;
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get {
            return _toolTipText;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _toolTipText) {
                _toolTipText = value;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_toolTipText)) {
                    _toolTip.Hide(this);
                    _hasError = false;
                } else {
                    _toolTip.Show(_toolTipText, this, 3000);
                    _hasError = true;
                }

                // This is required to update the border color immediately.
                var m = Message.Create(Handle, WM_NCPAINT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                WndProc(ref m); 
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (_hasError && m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT) {
            var dc = GetWindowDC(Handle);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc)) {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the tooltip text to something different than null or empty show the tooltip and shows a red border.

The data model (view model in a MVVM context) must then provide an error message and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Example:

```cs
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set {
            if (value != _text) {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextErrorMessage));
            }
        }
    }


    public string TextErrorMessage
    {
        get {
            return _text?.Length == 4
            ? null
            : "Please enter a text of length 4";
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now bind the `Text` property of the `TextBoxEx` to the `Text` property of the model and bind the `ToolTipText` property of the `TextBoxEx` to the `TextErrorMessage` property of the model. Set both bindings to `OnPropertyChanged` and assign a model object to the `DataSource` property of the `BindingSource` component on your form.

Now you have a full functional MVVM pattern requiring no code in the form other than assigning the model to the binding source.